# ps auxwww | grep psql - postgres not running with homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have installed Postgres 9.2.3 just now via Homebrew, initiated a db, and inputed the start command. It says "server starting", but whenever I try to do anything, it tells me:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here are the things I have already done to try and fix this:

1) Fixed the path in my bash profile by adding this text: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

2) uninstalled & reinstalled the pg gem

3) used the gem pristine function

4) tried uninstalling and reinstalling home-brew

5) removed the old version of postgres that came with the Mac

6) `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/pgsql_socket/`

Still, nothing I do works. I have even tried using the Postgres official installer and the Postgres App from Heroku. Nothing works.

It seems like I can't get postgres to run properly because when I run: `ps auxw | grep postgres`

I just get:

```
[MyName]        66744   0.0  0.0  2432768    596 s000  R+    8:47PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

nothing else shows up, which suggests that nothing else is running.

I noticed that my username for my Mac is Zephyr, but the username postgres is using is my actual name. Could that be the issue?

Which I do `which psql`, I get the correct path of: `/usr/local/bin/psql`

I have been trying to get this to work for hours and nothing seems to resolve this connection issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `psql` is the shell (the client), not the database itself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to setup postgresql manually which in some case is well hidden from user.
You can try these specific steps and see if it works(At least, worked in my Lion). Bear in mind, It is my local setup. I installed Postgresql from binary.

1. create a new folder named `data` in postgres folder(mine is at `/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/data`). Make sure your `chmod` that folder. `data` is just simple to remember.
2. run `initdb` to initialize postgres data. Mine is
   `/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/initdb -D
   /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/data`.
3. Start server:
   `/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_ctl -D
   /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/data start`

Tips: Put these paths into env variables.

Hope it helps :)